# Stream ftp file to browser

Tags: php, browser, ftp, stream

I am trying to retrieve and stream a file to the browser from an ftp site.

The error is:

> Warning: ftp_nb_get() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given

I know that it is a resource but how do I get around this?

```
if(isset($_GET['filename'])){
    $requestfilename = $_GET['filename'];

    if($sockets = stream_socket_pair(STREAM_PF_UNIX, STREAM_SOCK_STREAM, STREAM_IPPROTO_IP)){
        stream_set_write_buffer($sockets[0], 0);
        stream_set_timeout($sockets[1], 0);
        if($ftp_connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server)){
            if (@ftp_login($ftp_connection, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
                if(@ftp_chdir($ftp_connection, $ftp_dir_new)){
                    if($ret = ftp_nb_get($ftp_connection, $sockets[0], $requestfilename, FTP_BINARY)){
                        while(ftp_nb_continue($ftp_connection)==FTP_MOREDATA){
                            $contents = stream_get_contents($sockets[1]);
                            if($contents !== false) {
                                echo $contents;
                                flush();
                            }
                        }
                        if ($ret != FTP_FINISHED) $error[] = 'There was an error downloading the file...';
                    }else{
                    $error[] = "Could not ftp_nb_get file from $ftp_server";
                    }
                }else{
                    $error[] = "Couldn't cd to $ftp_dir_new";
                }
            } else {
                $error[] = "Couldn't connect as $ftp_user";
            }
        }else{
            $error[] =  "Couldn't connect to $ftp_server";
        }
    }else{
        $error[] = "Unable to create socket pair";
    }

    if($sockets){
        fclose($sockets[0]);
        fclose($sockets[1]);
    }
    if( ! empty($ftp_connection)) ftp_close($ftp_connection);
}
```

Comment: It wants a file name. Have you tried using the php:// files? See http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Yes I did try that, it also is a resource, same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're looking for an alternative to `ftp_nb_get()` that allows you to write to STDOUT or an arbitrary stream, instead of a local file?

I've not used this module at all, but it looks like [`ftp_nb_fget`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-fget.php) does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old topic, but I came across this code and found small bug. Maybe someone uses it and has problem making it work.

This code won't work for very small files because ftp_nb_continue won't return FTP_MOREDATA even once. To fix this you need to change while loop to:

```
while($ret == FTP_MOREDATA){
    $contents = stream_get_contents($sockets[1]);
    if($contents !== false) {
        echo $contents;
        flush();
    }
    $ret = ftp_nb_continue($ftp_connection);
}
```